# Datatype Mismatch in criteria expression using vb.NET, Access

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have tried with quotes around both variables, and have been searching for a solution to this. 
Querytext:

```
"UPDATE Customer SET RoundID =" & SelectedID & " WHERE CustomerID ='" & ctrl.Tag & "'"
```

SelectedID is an integer, 35 for example.
ctrl.Tag is also an integer.
I'm trying to update a field in my Customer table. RoundID is a long integer, CustomerID is an autonumber.
The database is stored in access, i am using Access 2013, and im writing in Visual Basic Express 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's both easier and safer to use parameters:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Customer SET RoundID = @SelectedID WHERE CustomerID = @Tag"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedID", SelectedID)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tag", ctrl.Tag)
```